# Android AChartEngine legened's settings

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there possible to set the spacing between the legend's fields?
How can I increase the square's size in the legend?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: U can hide the Legend. Create custom view to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no any function to do waht you need. 
You can download sources of this lib and implement such feature